# How is the Dehn invariant related to the mean width?

Tags: geometric-probability

Reading Ravi Vakils [Monthly article](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/files/monthly116-129-vakil.pdf) of february 2011 and watching the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jksQz4jhUqc); he mentions that the Dehn invariant is related to the linear invariant measure $\mu_1$ of geometric probability. The Klain Rota [book](http://books.google.com/books?id=Q1ytkNM6BtAC) discusses the Dehn invariant on pages 115-116. To make the question self contained:

Let $P \subset \mathbf{R}^3$ be a convex polyhedron.  Let $rP$ be the dilation of $P$ by the positive real number $r$.

The Dehn invariant of $P$ is an element of the real vector space $\mathbf{R} \otimes_{\mathbf{Z}} \mathbf{R}/(\pi\mathbf{Z})$, given by the formula
$$
D(P) = \sum_e \mu_1(e) \otimes (\text{angle between the two faces containing }e)
$$

The [mean width](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_width) $W(P)$ is a real scalar, given by generally by total integrated mean curvature over the surface but specially:
$$
W(P) = \sum_e\mu_1(e)(\text{angle deficiency from being flat of }e)
$$

Both $D$ and $W$ scale linearly with dilations: $D(rP) = rD(P)$ and $W(rP) = rW(P)$.  And the Dehn invariant is invariant under the scissors congruence relation, while the mean width [doesn't seem to.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/194635/is-mean-width-a-dehn-invariant)

Is this it or am I missing something?